# Why is it that I am not able to create a storefront controller in Shopware?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I need to create a simple Shopware 6 Controller... My problem is that even by copying the exact code from the docs/tutorial, I am not able to get the controller to work...

My error:

```
Call to a member function hasScope() on array
```

[This is the stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74mOl.png)

The code of my controller:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ArvKalbacherCustomization\Storefront\Controller;

use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"storefront"}})
 */
class ExampleController extends StorefrontController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/example", name="frontend.example.example", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function showExample(): Response
    {
        return $this->renderStorefront('@ArvKalbacherCustomization/storefront/page/example.html.twig', [
            'example' => 'Hello world'
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my service.xml

```
<service id="ArvKalbacherCustomization\Storefront\Controller\ExampleController" public="true">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
</service>
```

Here are my routes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import resource="../../Storefront/Controller/**/*Controller.php" type="annotation"/>
</routes>
```

I really hopy anyone can help me :)

Comment: Do you use the Shopware version 6.4.11.0 or newer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this must be version related as on the current trunk this works fine. [This commit](https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/fb623aa035897a471ef856682a5c484846de59a0) from `6.4.11.0` onwards introduced the `_routeScope` default as a replacement for the deprecated `@RouteScope` annotation.

Also see the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller#storefront-controller-class-example).

Comment: Yeah I figured that out too about an hour ago :)
Thank you so much though :D
I didn't know that the version this store uses is THAT much outdated... I wondered so much why this isn't working haha